# Last online (15 minutes ago)

Tags: php

I try to do mysql query, I want to load (or count) members, that was 15 ago online.
I try:

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM user WHERE `lastlogin` >  ".time()." - 3600;
```

But it doesn't work, i receive all membert list.
Where I have made a mistake?
Can you, please, help me?

Comment: share how `lastlogin` looks like ? any sample ?

Comment: nix time, like 1535994299

Comment: And that query in the context of your PHP code as currently its got odd quotes in it

Comment: can you please help me with correct one query?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the database's own time:

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM user WHERE `lastlogin` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I receive zero "0" as answer, but the result should be, there are data in db.